# Image slider using JQuery not displaying the next image I have selected but displays from the beginning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am very new to JQuery and all I need is to select a image displayed in a website on mouse click and display a popup slider containing that image.

I am getting it done but on clicking next it loads from the first image rather than showing the next image.

My code:

http://jsfiddle.net/MT7Ag/

```
    var myPos=0;
    $('#btnNext').click(function() {
        //copy this image to the placeholder
        $('#mimg').attr('src', $('.images .display').eq(myPos).attr('src'));
        myPos++;
        if(myPos==$('.images .display').length) {
        myPos = 0;
     }
    });
```

> If I click safari means it has to load ie next but it loads firefox(the first one).

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your position starts at 0. So even if you click safari it will still show the first image. You need to change myPos according to the image you clicked

Using the jquery index function you can find the index of the clicked element and update myPos.

```
$('.display').click(function() {
            myPos = $('img').index(this)+1;
            var sr=$(this).attr('src');
            $('#mimg').attr('src',sr);
          $('#myModal').show();
            $('.modal').show();
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MT7Ag/1

Comment: Thats what I am asking how to change that? I dont know.

Comment: hmmm...you could try http://api.jquery.com/index/ to get the index of the clicked element and update myPos

Comment: Post a sample please.